# Validate a SELECT against another SELECT PHP JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Within my form there are 2 SELECT Options. I'm looking to check the values of both, to check that they match.

This below is my jquery, when the code runs, I deliberatly have different values in the SELECT options and the form will just carry onto the next page without flagging up the error that they don't match.

```
     <script  type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {     
        jquery(function(){
            $("leadgenform2").click(function(){
               $(".error").hide();
                var hasError = false;
                var exppagesval = $("#exppages").val();
                var pagesseenval = $("#pagesseen").val();
                if (exppagesval != pagesseenval) {
                   $("#pagesseen").after('<div class="alert alert-success display-hide"><button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>Pages Seen & Expected Pages do not match!</div>');
                  hasError = true;
                }
                if(hasError == true) {return false;}
            });
         });
   });      
</script>
```

What have I missed?

Not sure why formatting has gone a miss. sorry!

Comment: You code made me a headache, can you format it on your own?

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("leadgenform2") is not a valid selector.  assuming it is an ID, so you should use $("#leadgenform2").

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry I was a dope and missed a few bits off! It wouldn't format for the life of me earlier. Have I missed anything else from the code, as testing with the changes it doesn't reveal the error when one doesn't match the other? I amended the code in my original thread

Comment: Using Chrome Inspect Element, I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined under this line ` jquery(function () {` I can't see what I'm missing. New to jquery

Comment: i hate to state the obvious, but did you include the jquery source .js file in your page ?

Comment: This jquery is written within the header of the page

Comment: most javascript is case sensitive. try changing it to jQuery(function()
http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: I took the jQuery(function() out of the code, this now errors when the SELECTS don't match. My problem now is that the error div doesnt show.

Answer (score 2):

hey $("leadgenform2") is invalid selector either make it a class or id(preferred) and use like

> - $(".leadgenform2") for class.
> - $("#leadgenform2") for id.

Answer (score 1):

Just from a first glance... you seem to have an error on line1:

```
jquey(function(){
```

should be

```
jquery(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

And you are missing `$(document).ready(function(){ .... );`
Without this, click event will not fire.